# Shortest possible resulting length after iterated string replacement

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, optimization

How would I go about reasonably efficiently finding the shortest possible output given by repeatedly applying replacements to an input sequence? I believe (please correct me if I am wrong) that this is exponential-time in the worst case, but I am not sure due to the second constraint below. The naive method certainly is.

I tried coding the naive method (for all possible replacements, for all valid positions, recurse on a copy of the input after applying the replacement at the position. Return the shortest of all valid recursions and the input, with a cache on the function to catch equivalent replacement sequences), but it is (unworkably) slow, and I'm pretty sure it's an algorithmic issue as opposed to the implementation.

A couple of things that may (or may not) make a difference:

- Token is an enumerated type.
- The length of the output of each entry in the map is strictly less than the input of the entry.
- I do *not* need what replacements were done and where, just the resulting sequence.

So, as an example where each character is a token (for simplicity's sake), if I have the replacement map as `aaba` -> `a`, `aaa` -> `ab`, and `aba` -> `bb`, and I apply minimalString('aaaaa'), I want to get 'a'.

The actual method signature is something along the following lines:

```
List<Token> getMinimalAfterReplacements(List<Token> inputList, Map<List<Token>, List<Token>> replacements) {
    ?
}
```

Is there a better method than brute-force? If not, is there, for example, a SAT library or similar that could be harnessed? Is there any preprocessing to the map that could be done to make it faster when called multiple times with different token lists but with the same replacement map?

Comment: I wish you would have started off with the problem statement. So you got from `aaaaa` to `a` by `a(aaa)a -> a(ab)a = (aaba) -> a`, is that it?

Comment: The second constraint is what makes it *decidable* (intuitively, if some replacements make the string longer, the path to the shortest string may lead through arbitrarily large strings; if no replacement expands the string there is an finite number of possibilities). This whole thing looks very much like recognizing context-sensitive grammars which is PSPACE-complete and hence unlikely to be doable in polynomial time even if you believe P=NP. However, that's just for worst-case complexity; most of your actual problems may be simpler. Also, are heuristics acceptable?

Comment: @Ben - correct. I didn't put it first because either I'd have to deal with Java's (absurd) verbosity in the example, or be unclear that I'm dealing with a list of tokens and not strings. Should I edit it to put the problem statement first?

Comment: I could imagine a couple of low level tricks bringing some speedup factor like 4 or maybe 10. Would it do for you? What's the current timing, what's needed? What about multitasking? How many different tokens, how may rules, and what's the input length? All this information could help low level optimizations.

Comment: @delnan - I would like the exact solution if at all possible. I concur with you on the decidability - without that rule I'm pretty sure you could express a Turing machine as state rewrites!

Comment: @maaartinus The curse of exponential growth is that there's only a very narrow windows where such constant factor improvements help. At the latest when adding a single tokens adds years of computation time, not even a 1000x speedup helps. *Maybe* OP's applications all fall into that narrow windows but that would have to be checked first.

Comment: @delnan That's why I'm asking. And maybe there's nothing much better than a small constant factor available, or maybe the OP will need it in addition to it. Actually, after finding a solution, it could be used to cut off some branches when a lower bound on length can be computed. I guess, the problem is [always decidable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncontracting_grammar#Transforming_into_context-sensitive_grammar).

Comment: I'd like to give it a try if you provide us with some data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is a Python version to find the shortest possible reduction. It is non-recursive but not too far from the naive algorithm. In every step it tries all possible single reductions, thus, obtaining a set of strings to reduce for the next step.

One optimization that helps in cases when there are "symbol eating" rules like "aa" -> "a" is to check the next set of strings for duplicates.

Another optimization (not implemented in the code below) would be to process the replacement rules into a finite automaton that finds locations of all possible single reductions with a single pass through the input string. This would not help the exponential nature of the main tree search algorithm, though.

```py
class Replacer:
  def __init__(self, replacements):
    self.replacements = [[tuple(key), tuple(value)] for key, value in replacements.items()]

  def get_possible_replacements(self, input):
    "Return all possible variations where a single replacement was done to the input"
    result = []
    for replace_what, replace_with in self.replacements:
      #print replace_what, replace_with
      for p in range(1 + len(input) - len(replace_what)):
        if input[p : p + len(replace_what)] == replace_what:
          input_copy = list(input[:])
          input_copy[p : p + len(replace_what)] = replace_with
          result.append(tuple(input_copy))
    return result

  def get_minimum_sequence_list(self, input):
    "Return the shortest irreducible sequence that can be obtained from the given input"
    irreducible = []
    to_reduce = [tuple(input)]
    to_reduce_new = []
    step = 1
    while to_reduce:
      print "Reduction step", step, ", number of candidates to reduce:", len(to_reduce)
      step += 1
      for current_input in to_reduce:
        reductions = self.get_possible_replacements(current_input)
        if not reductions:
          irreducible.append(current_input)
        else:
          to_reduce_new += reductions
      to_reduce = set(to_reduce_new[:]) # This dramatically reduces the tree width by removing duplicates
      to_reduce_new = []

    irreducible_sorted = sorted(set(irreducible), key = lambda x: len(x))
    #print "".join(input), "could be reduced to any of", ["".join(x) for x in irreducible_sorted]
    return irreducible_sorted[0]

  def get_minimum_sequence(self, input):
    return "".join(self.get_minimum_sequence_list(list(input)))

input = "aaaaa"

replacements = {
  "aaba" : "a",
  "aaa" : "ab",
  "aba" : "bb",
}

replacer = Replacer(replacements)
replaced = replacer.get_minimum_sequence(input)
print "The shortest string", input, "could be reduced to is", replaced
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a simple idea which might reduce the branching: With rules like

```
ba -> c
ca -> b
```

and a string like

```
aaabaacaa
   ^  ^
```

you can do two substitutions and their order doesn't matter. This is already sort of covered by memoization, however, there's still a considerable overhead for generating the useless string. So I'd suggest the following rule:

After a substitution on position `p`, consider only substitutions on positions `q` such that

```
q + length(lhs_of_the_rule) > p
```

i.e., such that don't start to the left of the previous substitutions or they overlap.

---

As a simple low-level optimization I'd suggest to replace the `List<Token>` by a `String` or (or an encapsulated `byte[]` or `short[]` or whatever). The lower memory footprint should help the cache and you can index an array by a string element (or two) in order to find out what rules may be applicable for it.

Comment: I have subsequently read this question as an algorithmic complexity question rather than a discussion of the specific implementation. Hence the comments about the PSPACE-complete nature of certain grammars. The rules he has described form the inverse of the non contracting grammar that you linked so he is interested in knowing the maximum reduction that can be achieved, and how it could be achieved in less than O(n^x) worst-case complexity.

Comment: @MatthewFranglen I see this question mainly as a practical problem. *If it was a purely theoretical question, then it'd be [misplaced here](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com).* Knowing that's a PSPACE problem is surely important - it tells us that we're out of luck. We won't find a fast solution. Still, there's no reason not to try to be as fast as possible.

Comment: @MatthewFranglen You seem to have misunderstood my link. It merely shows that *even* a non-contracting grammar can be transformed into a contracting one. This only means that your comment concerning decidability was wrong, that's all. What I'm missing, *why the downvote on the only non-deleted answer so far?*

Comment: I don't understand how your link demonstrates that a non-contracting grammar can be converted into a contracting grammar. It shows how it can be converted into a context sensitive grammar. After all, if the grammar has no way to reduce the length of the input then how can it become contracting? I downvoted your answer for the same reason that I deleted my own answer - it does not answer the question, which I read as "[is there a way that is better than] exponential-time in the worst case"

Comment: @MatthewFranglen I guess I was wrong with the link. But I can't follow the way how you understand the question. The OP is asking for a speed up, and there's nothing indicating "better than exponential". They're even asking for a SAT library, which does have an exponential worst time.

Comment: "I believe ... that this is exponential-time in the worst case, but I am not sure due to the second constraint below." and "Is there a better method than brute-force?" lead me to believe that he wants a better than exponential-time in the worst case. He is suggesting the SAT library if there is not a better solution.